Databricks String (XML) columns parsing
I'm trying to parse XML strings written in multiple rows of a table field
What i have:
1. Spark Dataframe
The dataframe is like this:

With this schema:
root
 |-- Id: decimal(18,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- OrderId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Action: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TrayportDateTimeUTC: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- GV8Data: string (nullable = true)

2. XML Sample
This is the sample of one XML string:
<GV8APIDATA
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="gv8api-trayport-com">
    <ORDER EngineID="1" PersistentOrderID="60076044" OrderID="52389917" OldEngineID="0" OldOrderID="0" Action="Remove" DateTime="2023-10-14T00:16:33.0467795Z" DateTimeNanoSecondsPart="0" Price="169.50" Volume="1" HiddenVolume="0" PriceDelta="0.00" Side="Ask" Status="Withheld" Company="Company" CompanyID="278" Broker="ICAP" BrokerID="4" User="User" UserID="1910" Trader="User" TraderID="1910" OrderType="GoodTillCancelled" AllOrNone="false" CounterPartyOk="false" SystemRank="55936541" ImpliedType="None" IsTradable="No" OrderDealt="false" TradingCapacity="DEAL" ExecutionMaker="19850428" DerivativeIndicator="false" DEA="false" LiquidityProvision="true" ProductClassification="RM - MIFID" IsMarketData="true" IsOwnData="true">
        <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="10641712" InstName="Germany Peaks EEX" FirstSequenceID="10000104" SeqSpan="Single" FirstSequenceItemID="240" SecondSequenceItemID="0" FirstSequenceItemName="Dec-23" SecondSequenceItemName="" TermFormatID="2906593310" ExternalInstID="10641712"/>
    </ORDER>
</GV8APIDATA>

From my checks the XML is well formatted
My Tentative
1. Spark Sql Fast Test
Using from_xml e schema_of_xml functions
%sql
SELECT from_xml('<GV8APIDATA
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="gv8api-trayport-com">
    <ORDER EngineID="1" PersistentOrderID="60076044" OrderID="52389917" OldEngineID="0" OldOrderID="0" Action="Remove" DateTime="2023-10-14T00:16:33.0467795Z" DateTimeNanoSecondsPart="0" Price="169.50" Volume="1" HiddenVolume="0" PriceDelta="0.00" Side="Ask" Status="Withheld" Company="Company" CompanyID="278" Broker="ICAP" BrokerID="4" User="User" UserID="1910" Trader="User" TraderID="1910" OrderType="GoodTillCancelled" AllOrNone="false" CounterPartyOk="false" SystemRank="55936541" ImpliedType="None" IsTradable="No" OrderDealt="false" TradingCapacity="DEAL" ExecutionMaker="19850428" DerivativeIndicator="false" DEA="false" LiquidityProvision="true" ProductClassification="RM - MIFID" IsMarketData="true" IsOwnData="true">
        <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="10641712" InstName="Germany Peaks EEX" FirstSequenceID="10000104" SeqSpan="Single" FirstSequenceItemID="240" SecondSequenceItemID="0" FirstSequenceItemName="Dec-23" SecondSequenceItemName="" TermFormatID="2906593310" ExternalInstID="10641712"/>
    </ORDER>
</GV8APIDATA>', schema_of_xml('<GV8APIDATA
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="gv8api-trayport-com">
    <ORDER EngineID="1" PersistentOrderID="60076044" OrderID="52389917" OldEngineID="0" OldOrderID="0" Action="Remove" DateTime="2023-10-14T00:16:33.0467795Z" DateTimeNanoSecondsPart="0" Price="169.50" Volume="1" HiddenVolume="0" PriceDelta="0.00" Side="Ask" Status="Withheld" Company="Company" CompanyID="278" Broker="ICAP" BrokerID="4" User="User" UserID="1910" Trader="User" TraderID="1910" OrderType="GoodTillCancelled" AllOrNone="false" CounterPartyOk="false" SystemRank="55936541" ImpliedType="None" IsTradable="No" OrderDealt="false" TradingCapacity="DEAL" ExecutionMaker="19850428" DerivativeIndicator="false" DEA="false" LiquidityProvision="true" ProductClassification="RM - MIFID" IsMarketData="true" IsOwnData="true">
        <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="10641712" InstName="Germany Peaks EEX" FirstSequenceID="10000104" SeqSpan="Single" FirstSequenceItemID="240" SecondSequenceItemID="0" FirstSequenceItemName="Dec-23" SecondSequenceItemName="" TermFormatID="2906593310" ExternalInstID="10641712"/>
    </ORDER>
</GV8APIDATA>')) test

and I obtain more or less the expected result

2. Spark Sql Estensive Test
Using from_xml e schema_of_xml functions
SELECT from_xml(GV8Data, schema_of_xml('STRUCT<ORDER: STRUCT<INSTSPECIFIER: STRUCT<_ExternalInstID: BIGINT, _FirstSequenceID: BIGINT, _FirstSequenceItemID: BIGINT, _FirstSequenceItemName: STRING, _InstID: BIGINT, _InstName: STRING, _SecondSequenceItemID: BIGINT, _SecondSequenceItemName: STRING, _SeqSpan: STRING, _TermFormatID: BIGINT>, _Action: STRING, _AllOrNone: BOOLEAN, _Broker: STRING, _BrokerID: BIGINT, _Company: STRING, _CompanyID: BIGINT, _CounterPartyOk: BOOLEAN, _DEA: BOOLEAN, _DateTime: TIMESTAMP, _DateTimeNanoSecondsPart: BIGINT, _DerivativeIndicator: BOOLEAN, _EngineID: BIGINT, _ExecutionMaker: BIGINT, _HiddenVolume: BIGINT, _ImpliedType: STRING, _IsMarketData: BOOLEAN, _IsOwnData: BOOLEAN, _IsTradable: STRING, _LiquidityProvision: BOOLEAN, _OldEngineID: BIGINT, _OldOrderID: BIGINT, _OrderDealt: BOOLEAN, _OrderID: BIGINT, _OrderType: STRING, _PersistentOrderID: BIGINT, _Price: DOUBLE, _PriceDelta: DOUBLE, _ProductClassification: STRING, _Side: STRING, _Status: STRING, _SystemRank: BIGINT, _Trader: STRING, _TraderID: BIGINT, _TradingCapacity: STRING, _User: STRING, _UserID: BIGINT, _Volume: BIGINT>, _xmlns: STRING, `_xmlns:xsd`: STRING, `_xmlns:xsi`: STRING>')) test
FROM PARQUET.`path_to_file/file.parquet`

things begin to get wrong

3. Pyspark Test
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, BooleanType, TimestampType

# INSTSPECIFIER
inst_specifier_schema = StructType([
    StructField("InstID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("InstName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("FirstSequenceID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("SeqSpan", StringType(), True),
    StructField("FirstSequenceItemID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("SecondSequenceItemID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("FirstSequenceItemName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("SecondSequenceItemName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("TermFormatID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ExternalInstID", StringType(), True)
])

# ORDER
order_schema = StructType([
    StructField("EngineID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("PersistentOrderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("OrderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("OldEngineID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("OldOrderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Action", StringType(), True),
    StructField("DateTime", StringType(), True),
    StructField("DateTimeNanoSecondsPart", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Price", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Volume", StringType(), True),
    StructField("HiddenVolume", StringType(), True),
    StructField("PriceDelta", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("Side", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Status", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Company", StringType(), True),
    StructField("CompanyID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Broker", StringType(), True),
    StructField("BrokerID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("User", StringType(), True),
    StructField("UserID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Trader", StringType(), True),
    StructField("TraderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("OrderType", StringType(), True),
    StructField("AllOrNone", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("CounterPartyOk", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("SystemRank", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ImpliedType", StringType(), True),
    StructField("IsTradable", StringType(), True),
    StructField("OrderDealt", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("TradingCapacity", StringType(), True),
    StructField("ExecutionMaker", StringType(), True),
    StructField("DerivativeIndicator", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("DEA", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("LiquidityProvision", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("ProductClassification", StringType(), True),
    StructField("IsMarketData", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("IsOwnData", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("INSTSPECIFIER", inst_specifier_schema, True)
])

# root
gv8api_data_schema = StructType([
    StructField("ORDER", order_schema, True)
])

df = spark.read.parquet("path_to_file/file.parquet")
parsed_df = df.withColumn("parsed_xml", from_xml("GV8Data",schema=order_schema))

My results
I receive this obscure error
Error in callback <bound method UserNamespaceCommandHook.post_run_cell of <dbruntime.DatasetInfo.UserNamespaceCommandHook object at 0x7fe060e563e0>> (for post_run_cell):

With no other details.
What am I missing?

Can you compile code in scala ? Im also using this trayport data and i developped a method in scala, compiled in a fat jar

Yes, I have no language limitations

I think this is the ugliest code I've written; it doesn't resolve my question, but it represents a working solution. Though it would be nice to make it more efficient, if someone knows how to.
Basically I use an UDF to convert the xml to a json using xmltodict and json, then I extract the struct from the dictionary using from_json.
import xmltodict, json
from pyspark.sql.functions import schema_of_json, from_json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, FloatType, BooleanType


# UDF to convert xml to json

def xmlparse(data):
    result = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(data)["GV8APIDATA"]["ORDER"])
    return result

xmlparse_udf = udf(xmlparse, StringType()) 

# Json schema

# INSTSPECIFIER element
inst_specifier_schema = StructType([
    StructField("@InstID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@InstName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@FirstSequenceID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@SeqSpan", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@FirstSequenceItemID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@SecondSequenceItemID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@FirstSequenceItemName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@SecondSequenceItemName", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@TermFormatID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@ExternalInstID", StringType(), True)
])

# ORDER element
order_schema = StructType([
    StructField("@EngineID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@PersistentOrderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@OrderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@OldEngineID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@OldOrderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Action", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@DateTime", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@DateTimeNanoSecondsPart", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Price", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("@Volume", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@HiddenVolume", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@PriceDelta", FloatType(), True),
    StructField("@Side", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Status", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Company", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@CompanyID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Broker", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@BrokerID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@OldBrokerID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@User", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@UserID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@Trader", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@TraderID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@OrderType", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@AllOrNone", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("@CounterPartyOk", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("@ImpliedType", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@IsTradable", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@OrderDealt", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("@Execution", StringType(), True),
    StructField("@IsMarketData", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("@IsOwnData", BooleanType(), True),
    StructField("INSTSPECIFIER", inst_specifier_schema, True)
])

# Execution

df = spark.read.parquet("path_to_file/file.parquet")
parsed_df = df.withColumn("GV8Data_json", xmlparse_udf("GV8Data")).withColumn("GV8Data_struct", from_json("GV8Data_json",schema=order_schema))


sorry for late answer,
you can use scala.xml native package to parse like,
you can then compile a fat jar or package to add it to your spark job
import spark.implicits._

case class ORDER(
  id: String
)

def parse(message: String) = {
  // Split cml content by "TRADE" like
  val node = scala.xml.XML.loadString(message)
  (node \ "ORDER").iterator.map(elem => {
    val id = (elem \ "@OrderID").text
    ORDER(id)
  })
}

val message = "<GV8APIDATA\n    xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"\n    xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\n    xmlns=\"gv8api-trayport-com\">\n    <ORDER EngineID=\"1\" PersistentOrderID=\"60076044\" OrderID=\"52389917\" OldEngineID=\"0\" OldOrderID=\"0\" Action=\"Remove\" DateTime=\"2023-10-14T00:16:33.0467795Z\" DateTimeNanoSecondsPart=\"0\" Price=\"169.50\" Volume=\"1\" HiddenVolume=\"0\" PriceDelta=\"0.00\" Side=\"Ask\" Status=\"Withheld\" Company=\"Company\" CompanyID=\"278\" Broker=\"ICAP\" BrokerID=\"4\" User=\"User\" UserID=\"1910\" Trader=\"User\" TraderID=\"1910\" OrderType=\"GoodTillCancelled\" AllOrNone=\"false\" CounterPartyOk=\"false\" SystemRank=\"55936541\" ImpliedType=\"None\" IsTradable=\"No\" OrderDealt=\"false\" TradingCapacity=\"DEAL\" ExecutionMaker=\"19850428\" DerivativeIndicator=\"false\" DEA=\"false\" LiquidityProvision=\"true\" ProductClassification=\"RM - MIFID\" IsMarketData=\"true\" IsOwnData=\"true\">\n        <INSTSPECIFIER InstID=\"10641712\" InstName=\"Germany Peaks EEX\" FirstSequenceID=\"10000104\" SeqSpan=\"Single\" FirstSequenceItemID=\"240\" SecondSequenceItemID=\"0\" FirstSequenceItemName=\"Dec-23\" SecondSequenceItemName=\"\" TermFormatID=\"2906593310\" ExternalInstID=\"10641712\"/>\n    </ORDER>\n</GV8APIDATA>"
val ds = Seq(message).toDS.flatMap(parse)
ds.show(false)

